# Reparenting in React.js

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

I wanted to know if i can move the child component from one element to another element without having to recreate the component.

Referring the case in the given attached image.

[gif image of behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3xgY.gif)

Is it possible to move the `<Components Two/>` in `<parent one>` to `<parent two>` without running the expensive operations within the `<Components Two/>` again ? ie not recreating the component again. Would useMemo make sense in here ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the library https://github.com/Paol-imi/react-reparenting. I have a view navigation use case, currently trying some experimenting with this.